# Webpack: ModuleNotFoundError for an unimported module

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, webpack, next.js

**The problem**

My project consists of a yarn monorepo in which, among various packages, there is a NextJS app and a configuration package (which is also shared with the server and a react-native application). In the configuration module what I do is to export the production keys if the environment is production, while if the project is under development, the development ones.

```
import { merge } from "lodash";
import { IConfig, RecursivePartial } from "./interfaces";
import { defaultKeys } from "./default.keys";
import { existsSync } from "fs";

const secretKeys: RecursivePartial<IConfig> = (function (env) {
  switch (env) {
    case "production":
      return require("./production.keys").productionKeys;

    default:
      try {
        if (!existsSync("./development.keys")) {
          return require("./production.keys").productionKeys;
        } else {
          return require("./development.keys").developmentKeys;
        }
      } catch (e) {
      }
  }
})(process.env.NODE_ENV);

export const keys = merge(defaultKeys, secretKeys) as IConfig;
```

Of course, the development configuration file is included in the .gitignore file and therefore does not exist during production.

This has always worked perfectly (with the server and the mobile app), and indeed, there was never the need to check with the fs module if the development.keys file exists (check which I added later).

However, I recently added a NextJs application to the project. I encountered no problems during development, however when I tried to deploy the app on Heroku I encountered this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './development.keys' in '/tmp/build_43d652bc/packages/config/dist/keys'
```

**What I did**

Initially, I thought it was a problem with the environment variables and that in production the development file was wrongly required.
However, I later realized that this was not the problem. And indeed, even placing the import of the configuration file for development in any place of the code, even following a return, the error continues to occur.

```
import { merge } from "lodash";
import { IConfig, RecursivePartial } from "./interfaces";
import { defaultKeys } from "./default.keys";
import { existsSync } from "fs";

const secretKeys: RecursivePartial<IConfig> = (function (env) {
  switch (env) {
    case "production":
      return require("./production.keys").productionKeys;

    default:
      try {
           if (!existsSync("./development.keys")) {
             return require("./production.keys").productionKeys; // <-------
        } else {
          return require("./production.keys").productionKeys; // <-------
        }

        require("./development.keys").developmentKeys;  // <------- This line should not be executed
      } catch (e) {
        return require("./production.keys").productionKeys;
      }
  }
})(process.env.NODE_ENV);

export const keys = merge(defaultKeys, secretKeys) as IConfig;
```

It is as if during the build, nextjs (or probably webpack) controls all the imports, without following the "flow" of the code.

I hope someone shows me where I am wrong because at the moment I am stuck. Thank you!

**Update**

Thanks to the ideas of [this](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6680#issuecomment-370800037) discussion  I changed my file which now looks like this:

```
const getConfigPath = (env?: string): string => {
  console.log(env);
  if (env === "production") return "production.keys";
  else return "development.keys";
};

const secretKeys: RecursivePartial<IConfig> = require("./" +
  getConfigPath(process.env.NODE_ENV)).keys;

export const keys = merge(defaultKeys, secretKeys) as IConfig;
```

However, now I'm running into another webpack error:

```
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
| import { IConfig, RecursivePartial } from "../interfaces";
> export declare const keys: RecursivePartial<IConfig>;
```

It is as if webpack does not recognize declaration files generated by typescript. However, the error is new and I have never encountered it. I believe it's due to the behavior of webpack pointed out in the linked discussion.

I trust in some help, since I  know little about webpack

**Edit**

This is my next.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");

 module.exports = {
    distDir: '../../.next',
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
        prependData: `@import "variables.module.scss";`
    },
    webpack: (config, { isServer }) => {
      if (!isServer) {
        config.resolve.fallback.fs = false;
      }
      return config;
    },
};
```

Basically they are the defult configurations. The only thing I have changed is the path for the build, I have made a sass file globle and I have momentarily added a piece of code to allow the use of the fs module, which however as you can see above I do not use it more. So I could take this configuration out.

Comment: Do I need to provide more information? Should I post an issue on github? I am really stuck.

Comment: do you have webpack.config file? can you check if you have @babel/preset-typescript ?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your attention. Essentially the configuration module doesn't use webpack, so it doesn't have a config file. But this module is imported into my server, which uses NestJS, for the API, and recently NextJs to render the pages. I think that both NestJS and NextJS use under the hood webpack, however even in this case I have not added specific configurations, so they should be the default ones. I honestly don't know if NextJS uses that plugin, but I know typescript support is built-in by default. I found the Webpack configuration file in the NextJS folder but it is minified.

Comment: Oh I see, Can you provide your next.config.js details here?

Comment: I've updated the question. Thanks again @deechris27

Answer (score 0):

You need the loader for typescript configured in your next.config.js

```
npm install || yarn add awesome-typescript-loader

module.exports = {

    distDir: '../../.next',
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths: [path.join(__dirname, 'styles')],
        prependData: `@import "variables.module.scss";`
    },

    webpack: (config, options) => {

      const { dir, defaultLoaders, isServer } = options;

      if (!isServer) {
        config.resolve.fallback.fs = false;
       }
    
      config.pageExtensions.push(".ts", ".tsx");
    
      config.resolve.extensions.push(".ts", ".tsx");
    
      config.module.rules.push({
        test: /\.tsx?$/,
        include: [dir],
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          defaultLoaders.babel,
          {
           loader: "awesome-typescript-loader",,
          },
        ],
     });
    
    return config;
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, it took me so long to answer, but I had to go through a series of trials and my mistakes. I managed to run your code (removing the line "config.pageExtensions.push(".ts", ".tsx"); ") but unfortunately the error did not change: Failed to compile.
../../../config/dist/keys/x/production.keys.d.ts
Module parse failed: Unexpected token (2:7)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file.
| import { IConfig, RecursivePartial } from "../interfaces";
> export declare const keys: RecursivePartial<IConfig>;
|